# Is the function $F : X \times \{0\} \cup A\times I \to Y$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, suppose that $A \subset X$ and set $I=[0,1]$. We assume that $X\times I$ has the product topology and $X \times \{0\}$, $A \times I$ and $X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I$ are considered subspaces of $X\times I$. Let $f : A \times I \to Y$ and $g : X \to Y$ be continuous maps, such that $f(a,0)=g(a), \forall a \in A$.

Now let's define $F : X \times \{0\} \cup A \times I \to Y$ by $F(x,t) = f(x,t)$, if $t \neq 0$, and $F(x,t) = g(x)$, if $t=0$. I'm trying to prove in detail that $F$ is continuous. My approach is to show that $F$ is continuous for every $(x,t)$ in the domain. Until now, I've proved that $F$ is continuous for every element in the domain expect for those elements in $(\overline{A} \setminus A) \times \{0\}$.

Is $F$ really continuous or is there a counterexample?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the set $A$ is closed then $F$ is continuous by (simple) Proposition 2.1.13 from Engelking’s “General topology” (see below). But if the set $A$ is not closed then the map $F$ is not necessarily continuous, as the following counterexample shows: $X=[0,1]$, $A=(0,1]$, $g\equiv 0$, $f(x,t)=\max\{0, 1-x/t\}$ if $t>0$.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks!! Very nice answer. I think f(x,t)=t/x also works.